# Dynamically adding AdSense to Wordpress sidebar

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

Some of the pages/posts on my wordpress site get pretty long and I think the sidebar looks goofy just sitting there blank and empty. Plus, that empty space is a lost opportunity to advertise. So, what I'm trying to do is use javascript to determine the height of the #main and then dynamically add Adsense script until the height of #sidebar is approximately equal (meaning another set of ads won't fit).

I've determined how to pull the height of both divs using offsetHeight (which I recognize isn't going to be perfect) and I understand the logic of running a do/while until the heights of the separate divs are equal.

Adsense code comes in two parts. The first part just sets some variables, the second calls some code and I suppose uses the variables from the first part. Both are required in order for adsense to display an ad. If both are present more than once, the ad will display more than once. I've dumped the first section of code into a separate .js file, so now I just need to figure out how to call both scripts with separate src attributes.

I found this code and adapted it to my situation  (I've put it in my header)but it doesn't work (displays nothing):

```
var sidebar= document.getElementById('sidebar')[0];
var script1 = document.createElement("script");
script1.type = "text/javascript";
script1.src = "link/to/javascript/file.js";

var script2 = document.createElement("script");
script2.type = "text/javascript";
script2.src = "http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js";

sidebar.appendChild(script1);
sidebar.appendChild(script2);
```

and I've tried the above code without the `[0]` because I didn't think I needed it. Neither option works.

Any ideas on how to pull this off the way I'm doing it? Any ideas on better ways to execute the code.

Comment: `document.getElementById('sidebar')` returns a DOM Node (or `null`). It's not an array. Using `[0]` would incorrect.

Comment: That's what I thought so I tried it without the [0] but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The solution given by JohnnyO here [Dynamic Adsense Insertion With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197768/dynamic-adsense-insertion-with-javascript)

worked fine for me.
The problem is with document.write() method inside Google's script.
write() method do not works after page has been loaded.