# using js/jquery to populate google adsense

Tags: javascript, jquery, adsense

I am trying to incorporate my own advertisement module for my website, if their are no ads to be displayed it defaults to google adesense ad

I currently have

```
if(this.ad_found)
//run code to display ad
else {
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-";
    /* Name */
    google_ad_slot = "-----";
    google_ad_width = ---;
    google_ad_height = ---;

    var head = document.getElementById('id_from_display_page')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = '//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
    $("#id_from_display_page").html(script);
}
```

as you can tell I have no idea how to populate id 'id_from_display_page' to display the google adsense stuff

The display page:

```
<div id="id_from_display_page"></div>
```

I want to populate this div with google adsense

Answer (score 0):

### EDITS:

This time, we're going to wrap all of this in a self-executing function.  Also, we'll make new elements and stick em in the `body` at the end.  Here's the cheat sheet:

### Javascript:

```
(function (window, document) {
    if (ad_found) {
        //run code to display ad
    } else {
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-";
        /* Name */
        google_ad_slot = "-----";
        google_ad_width = "---";
        google_ad_height = "---";

        var head = document.createElement('div');
        head.id = "id_from_display_page";
        var script = '<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript"><\/script>';
        head.innerHTML = script;
        document.body.appendChild(head);
    }
})(this, this.document, undefined);
```

Unfortunately without those variables set I have no way of actually testing this.  But I decided to place the `<script>` inside of a **new** `<div>` element that would have to get parsed by the DOM and should result in the code being executed as expected.

Keep me posted.

*Besides the missing variables, everything seems smooth with the fiddle I made below :)*

### [Demooooooooo](http://jsfiddle.net/WXqwb/)

Comment: EDIT: It is running the script, I tested with another js file that alerts hi, and it did. The google adsense stuff isn't showing though

Comment: Found my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197768/dynamic-adsense-insertion-with-javascript

Comment: hahahaha well to be ABSOLUTELY SURE you've got a backup set of code I just re-did for you.  Either way you go, you can't go wrong really.