# Several Adsense Slots Insertion With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, adsense

I need to insert several AdSense Slots in the same page using javascript.

As you can see in [Dynamic Adsense Insertion With JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197768/dynamic-adsense-insertion-with-javascript), it's needed to rewrite the document.write that use the global vars google_ad_client, google_ad_slot, etc..

Like this:  (Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/188740/johnnyo)

```
<script>
window.google_ad_client = "123456789";
window.google_ad_slot = "123456789";
window.google_ad_width = 200;
window.google_ad_height = 200;

// container is where you want the ad to be inserted
var container = document.getElementById('ad_container');
var w = document.write;
document.write = function (content) {
    container.innerHTML = content;
    document.write = w;
};

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js';
document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```

The issue is: If we have just one globla var for slot... How can we insert several ads in the same page using Javascript ?