# Want to display advertisement when I click href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ads

I am using the below script to display my advertisement. I am using onclick to display my advertisement. I am  try following code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="doalert(this); return false;" >Click here</a>

function doalert(obj) {
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- xxxxxxxxxxxx -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
}
```

I want to check the page without click to advertisement are load.

Requirement- I am click the link for display advertisement. Otherwise no load advertisement.

Comment: I think you need to learn JS, and how to insert basic HTML using JS.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Dynamic Adsense Insertion With JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197768/dynamic-adsense-insertion-with-javascript)