# How to add google adsense in Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, adsense

I've already tried to put it as custom directive, but JS reject script tag in any strings (unterminated literal string). Also, vue-google-adsense and vue-adsense plugins doesn't work for me, because they don't get all parameters that Adsense gives, so ads becomes not responsive etc.

Comment: Have a look here, maybe it can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197768/dynamic-adsense-insertion-with-javascript/15841383#15841383

Comment: Thank you, but I've seen it before :(

Comment: I used vue-meta and it works great for me. Article: https://www.the-koi.com/projects/a-step-by-step-guide-on-integrating-google-adsense-into-vout-vue-project/

Answer (score 13):

In the `index.html` file, add the adsense code out of the #app :

```
<div id="app"></div>
<div id="divadsensedisplaynone" style="display:none;">
    <!-- put here all adsense code -->
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
        style="display:block"
        data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxx"
        data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"
        data-ad-format="auto"
        data-full-width-responsive="true"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
</div>
```

In your main `App.vue` or any Vue file, add this where you want the ad to be shown (you are free to change the style) :

```
<div id="adsgoeshere" style="background: #1d1f29; padding-top:60px; text-align: center;" v-html="adsenseContent"></div>
```

In the `data` add :

```
 adsenseContent: ''
```

Finally, in the `mounted` function, add :

```
this.adsenseContent = document.getElementById('divadsensedisplaynone').innerHTML
```

And that's it !
You don't need any library.

Comment: It throws this:adsbygoogle.js:1 Uncaught 
H
message: "adsbygoogle.push() error: Fluid responsive ads must be at least 250px wide: availableWidth=0" :(

Comment: Try with a banner non responsive but fixed size like horizontal banner 320x50

Comment: Probably it will work, but I need responsive ad. I tried to make style of divadsensedisplaynone div equal to "visibility: hidden", and it started to work! Buuut... I had two banners - one on the top of the page, and one in place where I added it :D I am close to giving up with this because I lost at least two days on it. This is stupid

Comment: I spent a lot of time too. I don't understand why adsense JS code is so poor with many document.write() and no Vue.JS support. Sorry it doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is not the type of hack I'm looking for.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution yet? Same problem for me.

Comment: You can simply assign the style to a CSS class as a `computed` property and return the correct height and/or width accordingly, or assign it with JS on `mounted()` with something like `element.style.minHeight = '22px !important'`